# Simplest way to get XML nodes with namespace?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<createTransactionResponse xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd" 
                          xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <messages>
      <resultCode>Ok</resultCode>
      <message>
         <code>I00001</code>
         <text>Successful.</text>
      </message>
   </messages>
   <transactionResponse>
      <responseCode>1</responseCode>
      <authCode>25C10X</authCode>
      <messages>
         <message>
            <code>1</code>
            <description>This transaction has been approved.</description>
         </message>
      </messages>
  </transactionResponse>
</createTransactionResponse>
```

What is the easiest way to get the value "Successful." from `createTransactionResponse->messages->message->text`?

Here is my code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
var nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("anet", "AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd");
var myNodes = doc.SelectNodes("//anet:messages", nsmgr);
```

myNodes returns 2 nodes. The innerxml of node[0] is:

```
<resultCode xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">Ok</resultCode><message xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
   <code>I00001</code>
   <text>Successful.</text>
</message>
```

The innerxml of node[1] is:

```
<message xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
   <code>1</code>
   <description>This transaction has been approved.</description>
</message>
```

My problem is I can't go any deeper than that.

`//anet:messages/message` yields nothing.
`//anet:createTransactionResponse/messages` yields nothing.

I'm just trying to get specific element values such as "I00001" and "25C10X".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This solid question is way over-downvoted.  It is not obvious to beginners that default namespaces apply to descendant elements.  Plus, OP has a provided a [mcve] as needed.  I'm upvoting and bumping the edit timestamp; hopefully some of the harsh downvotes will  see and reverse.

Comment: @kjhughes agreed. It’s a clear and concise statement of the problem.

Comment: I'm used to it. There are people who run around SO downvoting for no reason. Probably the same people who scratch profanities in bathroom stalls. SO could so EASILY put a stop to this by making downvotes non-anonymous, or at least requiring a reason when downvoting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Namespace bindings are inherited, so the child elements are in the same namespace as their parents here.

You need to add the missing namespace prefixes to your query:

```
//anet:messages/anet:message/anet:text
```

That said, I'd usually prefer LINQ to XML over XPath:

```
XNamespace ns = "AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd";

var root = XElement.Parse(xml);

var text = (string) root.Elements(ns + "messages")
    .Descendants(ns + "text")
    .Single();
```

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3imtMb) for a working demo.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the LocalName property to avoid using the namespace:

```
XDocument root = XDocument.Parse(xml);

string text = root.Descendants()
    .First(node => node.Name.LocalName == "messages").Elements()
    .First(node => node.Name.LocalName == "message").Elements()
    .First(node => node.Name.LocalName == "text").Value;
```